SPI Data Transfer to 74HC595
I want to send data to my 74HC595 via SPI (in Arduino).
But I could not manage to blink my LEDs. My code is in below.
#include <SPI.h>

int clock_pin = 13; // SCLK
int data_pin = 11;  // MOSI
int latch_pin = 10; // SS

uint8_t led ;
void setup() {
  pinMode(latch_pin, OUTPUT); // enable pin 10 as latch pin
  
  // SPI Setup
  SPI.begin();
  SPI.setClockDivider(SPI_CLOCK_DIV8); 
  SPI.setBitOrder(LSBFIRST);  
  digitalWrite(latch_pin, HIGH);
}

void loop() {
  led = 0b10101111;
  put_Register(led);
  delay(500);  
  led = 0b10101101;
  put_Register(led);
  delay(5000);                  
}

void put_Register(byte led) {
  digitalWrite(latch_pin, LOW);
  SPI.transfer(led);       
  digitalWrite(latch_pin, HIGH);
}


It doesn't matter much but you wrote HC595 in the question and HC596 in the topic.

Well, how did you wire the Arduino to 74HC595? Supply? Ground? Correctly connected LEDs? With series resistors? Also, is this about the electronics or using Arduino libraries? With cases like this the Arduino libraries are unknown black boxes. It may also be the MCU does not run the code properly.

You should always describe what you expect to see and what you actually see in as much detail as possible. A schematic is usually useful as well. Just saying it doesn't work is not adequate and you will probably not receive good answers.

Which Arduino board are you using? This SPI pinout might be correct for an Uno, but not for other boards.

Also note that https://arduino.stackexchange.com/ exists

Your latch signal timing is wrong. Is is low during a serial transfer and needs a short positive pulse to transfer the shift register content to the output register.
Do not forget to set the output enable pin /OE to low and master reset /MR to high.
void setup() {
  //.... 
  pinMode(latch_pin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(latch_pin, LOW);  // initial low
}


void put_Register(byte led) {
  SPI.transfer(led);       
  digitalWrite(latch_pin, HIGH);  // short high pulse on STCP
  digitalWrite(latch_pin, LOW);
}


The latch signal timing is not wrong. The 74HC595 latch signal is sensitive to rising edge. It really does not care if you send data to it with latch signal high or low, or whether you give it a high pulse or low pulse.

@Justme Yes, my bad. It is edge triggered.
